# reduce a differential equation $y^{'}=\dfrac{1+y}{1-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to reduce a differential equation.
$$y^{'}=\dfrac{1+y}{1-x}$$
I reduce this, but my answer don't much "[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D%281%2By%29%2F%281-x%29&lang=ja)".
Please tell me what is wrong.

---

divide both sides of the equality by $(1+y)$
$$\dfrac{y'}{1+y}=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$
integrate both sides by $x$
$$\int \dfrac{1}{1+y}dy=\int \dfrac{1}{1-x}dx$$
$$\log \left| 1+y\right| =-\log \left| 1-x\right| +C$$
$$1+y=\dfrac{C}{1-x}$$
Last
$$y=\dfrac{C}{1-x}-\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your calculations

$$1+y = \dfrac C {1-x} \implies y = \dfrac C{1-x} - 1$$

which is already the solution.

If you want to obtain the form given by WolframAlpha, notice that:

$$\frac C{1-x} - 1 = \frac C{1-x}-\frac 1{1-x} + \frac x{1-x} = \frac{C-1}{1-x}+\frac x{1-x}$$

and $C-1$ is absorbed into $C$ since $C$ can be any constant, giving

$$y = \frac {c_1}{1-x}+\frac x{1-x}$$

Comment: I can understand. Thank you very much.